# Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) + Key-Value Observing (KVO)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, grand-central-dispatch, key-value-observing

I have a method in which I add observers:

```
- (void) method
{
    [currentPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"some" options:some context:some];
}
```

All the changes are processed in these method:

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

If I modify my method to:

```
- (void) method
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        [currentPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"some" options:some context:some];
    });
}
```

Does it mean that `- (void) observeValueForKeyPath...` will work in `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH`?

P.S. I want KVO to work in DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH.

EDIT:

I observe AVPlayer variables. Such as:

```
[currentPlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem.loadedTimeRanges" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:kTimeRangesKVO];
```

These variables are changed automatically.

Every time "observeValueForKeyPath" is called I check the queue and it remains `dispatch_get_main_queue()` and I don't know how to change it to some other queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an observer you can't control what thread / queue observeValueForKeyPath is called from.  You could wrap a dispatch onto the queue you wish around the work this method doing.  That will move the work of the observation to the high priority queue.

Just be sure you're aware this work is likely to be running on a different thread / queue than the code that triggered the observation.  If the object you're observing is not thread safe you will need to inspect it prior dispatching the rest of the work onto a different queue.

Answer (score 3):

No, if you want that the observeValueForKeyPath method gets executed with a higher priority, you have to change the key value from a thread with higher priority.KVO works synchronously, so the observeValueForKeyPath method gets executed on the same thread where you change the key value.

Comment: But I don't change the key value. I'm just an observer

Comment: *Something* changes the key's value.  The KVO notification is sent on whatever thread or queue the *something* is running on.

Comment: I've tried to make it run on the needed queue but unsuccessfully

Comment: This case you should directly use notifications.

Comment: To provide a quick bit of insight: when you install a key-value observer, the runtime substitutes your existing setter method for one that calls 'will change' for observers, calls the old setter, then calls 'did change' for observers. So you get exactly the same effect as if whoever called the setter also called the observers. The runtime isn't trapping anything ala a debugger, it's silently switching method implementations.